# Indexing arguments passed to for loop

Tags: r

Basically, I would like a for loop that goes from 10:15, then 20:25.
How would that be possible? My attempt so far was the following (which seems overly complex and doesn't work). I hope that the none working code gives an idea of what I want to achieve.

```
# dummy data set
V1 <- as.data.frame(rnorm(20, 0, 1))

## attempt
i <- c(10, 20)
j <- c(15, 25)
a <- 1
for(a in 1:length(i)) {
for(i[a] in i[a]:j[a]) {
...
}
}
```

In words: With the first (outer) for loop, I attempt to index which values of i (start) and j (end) of the respective vector are passed to the second (inner) for loop. So what I would like to have, by that, in the inner for loop would be:

1st:

```
for(10 in 10:15) {
... }
```

2nd:

```
for(20 in 20:25) {
... }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a vector that is the combination of the two vectors and then run the code

```
a <- seq(10,15)
b <- seq(20,25)
c <- c(a,b)

for(i in seq(1,length(c))){
  print(c[i])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing a nested loop??? If not then this code should work:

```
s <- c(10:20,25:30,35:40)
for(p in s) {
   #your manipulations here. eg
   print(p)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on understanding of your requirement, i think the most simple solution would be:

```
 a <- 10:15
 b <- 20:25
 c <- c(a,b)
 for(i in 10:15){
  print(c[i])
 }
 for(i in 20:25){
  print(c[i])
 }
```